# An error was encountered while initializing templates Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, razor-pages

I get this error when I try to add a Razor Page:

[image]

I've tried cleaning the project and even repairing Visual Studio via the installer to no avail.

Opening the indicated log, I can see at the end:

```
<entry>
    <record>3545</record>
    <time>2021/01/26 11:36:35.647</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Template Bootstrapper</source>
    <description>Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path &apos;&apos;, line 1, position 25.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings settings)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json, JsonLoadSettings settings)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.SettingsLoader.EnsureInstallDescriptorsLoaded()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.SettingsLoader.WriteInstallDescriptorCache()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.SettingsLoader.Save(TemplateCache cacheToSave)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.SettingsLoader.Save()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.ComponentManager.Save()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.ComponentManager.RegisterMany(IEnumerable`1 typeList)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.IDE.Bootstrapper.Register(Assembly assembly)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateEngine.Shared.Host.TemplateEngineBootstrapperFactory.TemplateEngineBoostrapper.Register(Assembly assembly)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateEngine.TemplateEngineHostManager.InitializeEngine()</description>
  </entry>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try updating Visual Studio to the latest version. That solve our issue when we encountered the same problem